# Frame animation with transparent background

Tags: android, animation

I want to use animation like progress bar.

I have the xml file prog_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress01"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress02"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress03"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress04"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress05"
    android:duration="100"/>
</animation-list>
```

File progress0x.png looks like this (for example)

[image: png with transparent background]

Background in this file is transparent.

In activity's layout xml I have imageview

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_logo2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_logo2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in java file

```
AnimationDrawable ad;
ImageView iv_pb;
...
iv_pb = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_pb);
iv_pb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.prog_drawable);

ad = (AnimationDrawable)iv_pb.getBackground();
ad.start();
```

When I launch my application I see this animation, but with black background. How can I get transparent background?

Comment: you should use .png format image. jpeg and gif dont support transparency and their transparency is not respected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you are setting `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to your `ImageView` for transparent background, but calling `iv_pb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.prog_drawable);` overrides this, causing your animation-drawable to be set as new background.

So, eventually you need to implement transparency in your image files. Make sure all the files are in `.png` with their background set as transparent.